# I am trying to pivot a dataset with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

This is the sample of the dataset

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtESW.png

This is the result i am trying to achieve

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnHpS.png

Here is my code:

```
df.pivot( values = ['Image Name'],index=['sku','Name of product']).reset_index()
```

Here is the dataset

```
sku,Name of product,Image Name

155280,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm.jpg
155280,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm2.jpg
155280,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm3.jpg
155280,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm,Catalinaresin planter in white H 100cm4.jpg
```

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't be posting datasets as images: please post text that we can cut and paste into our editors

Comment: Thanks i was unaware of that. just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
 pd.pivot_table(data=df,index='sku',columns='Image Name',values='Name of product',aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x))
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  finally got it working .You are awesome

Comment: you can approve the answer by clicking the tick mark, @anonnoob

Comment: sorry i didnot knew that. Thank you for your help